# .htaccess not being loaded in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I'm trying to use the `.htaccess` file in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7).

Here is what my `.htaccess` looks like

```
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|svg|woff|eot|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# Add correct content-type for fonts 
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/x-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml
```

I enabled mod_rewrite using `a2enmod rewrite`

Then I edited `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as follows

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
```

However the `.htaccess` file is still not being loaded. If I add gibberish to the `.htaccess` file everything still works fine. The `.htaccess` is located in `/var/www/`.

Here is the output of `apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost edmhunters.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/edmhunters.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.edmhunters.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

What did I miss here?

Here is the output of `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it on the domain ´edmhunters.com` if so you need to check the `edmhunters.com.conf` for that domain and look at its DocumentRoot as its where the `.htaccess` should be if that is the case.

Comment: @Prix I had `DocumentRoot /home/jaskaran/edmhunters` in my `edmhunters.com.conf`. I copied the `.htaccess` file there but I'm getting a 500 error now. I've added the error.log to my question.

Comment: Comment all the lines of your `.htaccess` and uncomment it piece by piece to see if anything is causing the issue and what

Comment: @Prix Adding `AllowOverride All` for the root directory in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` removed the 500 error. Should I have done that since my document root is at a different location that `/var/www/`? I also see that `.htaccess` file is now being loaded, but the compression and Cache-Control headers are still not working.

Comment: do you have the modules enabled within you server to allow those to work? Yes, its preferable you have the Directory options per `VirtualHost`.

Comment: @Prix Yes, I do. I've added the list of loaded modules to question.

Comment: how have you tested it to know the compression is not working? As far as I can tell `http://www.edmhunters.com/` is being compressed.

Comment: @Prix Using the [Google PageSpeed Insights tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.edmhunters.com&tab=desktop). Oddly enough, after using this `.htaccess` file 2 things - Minify HTML and Minify CSS, which were working before are now also coming under 'Consider Fixing'. That is probably due to `DEFLATE` overriding the default Gzip compression.

Comment: Possible yes, but as far as I can see it seems to be compressing and cached as I get a 304 not modified. You can also view these from Chrome's development tool aka F12.

Comment: @Prix You are correct. It seems like it's working fine for static files which have fixed URL path like most of the `jpg's`. However it's not working for static files whose names end with digits created on the fly. We'll I'll have to figure that out. Please add your comment about the `DocumentRoot` as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The isssue was that I was placing the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/` while my `DocumentRoot` for my website was pointing to a different directory. Moving the `.htaccess` file to that folder solved the issue.

Comment: lol, I had the same silly mistake, thanks for the tip :) spent several hours to find it -_-

Answer (score 11):

apache by default has .htaccess turned off now.

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` you should be able to find lines similar to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change that to

```
AllowOverride All
```

then restart apache and it should work.

You can over ride on a site by site basis also in the `sites-enabled` folder if you wish

Theres more than once place AllowOverride None, do a search for AllowOverride

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've already done what you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes, I did restart the server.

Comment: Worked for me. I was going over and over the site-available configs (which now have to end in *.config to work).