# Am I missing something for .htaccess redirect to https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https, lamp

I'm trying to get all traffic to direct from http to https:

www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

example.com -> https://example.com

The server is an AWS EC2 instance running LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04 ([setup tutorial used](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

The SSL certificates were generated by Let's Encrypt for both example.com and www.example.com ([tutorial used](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

I've gone through a dozen SO answers and other tutorials, and none of the .htaccess example code provided work for me. Here is a list of a few I have tried, without any success (I've tried uploading the file through SFTP and SSH editing through nano):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

,

```
RewriteEngine On
# https/http www -> https non-www
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# http non-www -> https non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
https://www.primesoft.in
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, it turns out Apache by default has .htaccess turned off. This answered solved it:
[.htaccess not being loaded in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816136/htaccess-not-being-loaded-in-ubuntu-14-04-apache-2-4-7)